# returning records with same primary key but different values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am hoping this is not a difficult question and hoping I explain this enough for someone to understand.  In the query below, what I am trying to do is find an account(a.acct_no) where an account is on the ina table has 2 records.  One record where one acct_no has an IRA_TYPE of 'IR' and one where a different account number has an IRA_TYPE of 'RH'.  They also need to have the same tax_id which is why I joined it with the ACT_TABLE.  I was able to use this query to find a similar tax id for 2 accounts that have IR and RH by scrolling through it until I landed on two records that met the requirements but I am trying to see how I can rewrite this query to only return one account coded 'IR' and one account coded 'RH' where the accounts have matching tax_ids.

```sql
SELECT a.acct_no, a.ira_type, b.tax_id
FROM INA a
inner join ACT_TABLE b on a.acct_no = b.acct_no
where a.ira_type in ('IR', 'RH')
group by b.tax_id, a.acct_no, a.ira_type
--having count(*) > 1
order by tax_id
```

Here is a sample of what I am scrolling though:

| acct_no | ira_type | tax_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 48192627 | IR | 001000001 |
| 17421898 | IR | 001103846 |
| 21041289 | IR | 001103846 |
| 32512838 | RH | 001103846 |
| 55413417 | RH | 001103846 |
| 65464636 | IR | 001103846 |
| 52779378 | IR | 001737922 |
| 53703374 | IR | 002134567 |
| 40681537 | RH | 002947454 |
| 69438955 | RH | 004411000 |
| 83680957 | RH | 004710909 |
| 64554609 | IR | 007329321 |
| 36936217 | IR | 008671784 |
| 70101808 | IR | 008958881 |

Comment: Could you please tag your RDBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query can help:

```sql
SELECT b.tax_id, ir.acct_no as ir, rh.acc_no as rh
FROM ACT_TABLE b
LEFT JOIN INA ir ON b.acct_no = ir.acct_no AND ir.ira_type = 'IR'
LEFT JOIN INA rh ON b.acct_no = rh.acct_no AND rh.ira_type = 'RH'
WHERE ir.acct_no <> rh.acc_no
```

Comment: You would want inner joins. But even then you'll get all possible pairs of the two account types.

Answer (score 0):

This simple change may be usefull

```
SELECT max(a.acct_no) as a.acct_no, a.ira_type, b.tax_id
FROM INA a
inner join ACT_TABLE b on a.acct_no = b.acct_no
where a.ira_type in ('IR', 'RH')
group by b.tax_id, a.ira_type
order by tax_id
```

Comment: Thank you this is closer to what I am looking for.  Just a follow up question.  Is there a way to customize it further.  I only want to see records that have at least on IR and one RH for each account number.  For example I do not want to see the 3rd or 4th record...

acct_no | ira_type | tax_id
--- | --- | ---
88695404 | IR | 000000000
22382970 | RH | 000000000
64839442 | IR | 000003333
48192627 | IR | 001000001
65464636 | IR | 001103846
55413417 | RH | 001103846

Comment: Sorry I am not exactly sure how to get that in a table format

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select b.tax_id, a.acct_no, a.ira_type,
        min(a.ira_type) over (partition by b.tax_id) as mn,
        max(a.ira_type) over (partition by b.tax_id) as mx,             
        row_number() over (partition by b.tax_id, a.ira_type order by a.acct_no) as rn
    from INA a inner join ACT_TABLE b
        on a.acct_no = b.acct_no and a.ira_type in ('IR', 'RH')
)
select tax_id, acct_no, ira_type
from data
where mn <> mx and rn = 1 /* make sure both types are represented and keep just one */
order by tax_id, ira_type;
```

or if you wanted them in the same row together:

```
select ir.tax_id, ir.acct_no as ir_acct_no, rh.acct_no as rh_acct_no
from
(
    select b.tax_id, min(a.acct_no) as acct_no, 'IR' as ira_type
    from INA a inner join ACT_TABLE b on a.acct_no = b.acct_no
    where a.ira_type = 'IR'
    group by b.tax_id
) as ir
inner join
(
    select b.tax_id, min(a.acct_no) as acct_no, 'RH' as ira_type
    from INA a inner join ACT_TABLE b on a.acct_no = b.acct_no
    where a.ira_type = 'RH'
    group by b.tax_id
) as rh
    on ir.tax_id = rh.tax_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/F3J588GF

Answer (score 0):

This will may be help you :

```
SELECT a.acct_no, a.ira_type, b.tax_id FROM INA a
inner join ACT_TABLE b on a.acct_no = b.acct_no
where a.ira_type in ('IR', 'RH')
group by b.tax_id, a.ira_type
order by tax_id
OR
SELECT Max(a.acct_no), a.ira_type, b.tax_id FROM INA a
inner join ACT_TABLE b on a.acct_no = b.acct_no
where a.ira_type in ('IR', 'RH')
group by b.tax_id, a.ira_type
order by tax_id
```